# URL Rewriting $_GET

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I made my own MVC app. And I am using the following RewriteRule in an `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

Then when i go to this url:

```
http://localhost/myapp/dahsboard/index
```

I get my variable `$_GET['p']=dahsboard/index` & it works.

But I use AutoComplete from jQueryUI with Ajax and it send a variable `$_GET['term']` with the value of the input used by AutoComplete.

My URL is then:

```
http://localhost/myapp/dashboard/index?term='myvalue'
```

My `.htaccess` doesn’t resolve it and I don't know how to.

Comment: ...aaaaand I assume you want to know how to transport that query parameter unharmed through your RewriteRule?

Comment: I wish short answers were permitted... add `[QSA]` to the end of your RewriteRule (put a space between "1" and "[QSA]" though!)

Comment: @Alexking2005 - you might as well accept one of the two already submitted answers - my answer wouldn't be any better than them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.  Change your RewriteRule from this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

To this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which uses the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) which will carry over the query string to the rewritten destination.

So when you go to this URL:

```
http://localhost/myapp/dahsboard/index?term='myvalue'
```

It will be passed on like this:

```
http://localhost/myapp/dahsboard/index.php?p=index&term=myvalue
```

And if I place the following in `index.php`:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

The returned output is:

```
Array
(
    [p] => index
    [term] => 'myvalue'
)
```

Additionally, if you want to easily debug the results you can do so by using `R` flag in addition to the `L` & `QSA` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

And then run a `curl -I` to check the Apache headers which should tell you where it will send the URL to via the `Location:` header:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8888/myapp/dahsboard/index?term='myvalue'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 16:07:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
Location: http://localhost:8888/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/dahsboard/index.php?p=index&term=myvalue
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Now yes, the `R` flag adds extra path info of `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` to the URL I am not 100% clear on why that happens. But for basic debugging like this, you can read the headers nicely to see that the final destination of `index.php?p=index&term=myvalue` is being sent. And once you know that,  remove the `R` flag when you put these rules into production.

FWIW, the `http://localhost:8888/Applications/MAMP/` reflects my local MAMP setup in Mac OS X. So ignore that. Your local setup will most likely return 100% different info. But the basic concept is solid.

Comment: Actually my index.php is in myapp folder. If i follow your recommandation my print_r($_GET); return me: Array ( [0] => dashboard [1] => search ) The url is: http://localhost/logipsy/dashboard/search?term=to

Comment: i created a directory called "myapp" in C: and created an alias in WAMP named "myapp", the .htaccess is in "myapp" directory.

Comment: you're right, it work with a simple index.php containing print_r... i'll find out why it don't work with my index.php. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's works perfectly! Thanks a lot. My mistake: echo $_GET instead of print_r

Answer (score 0):

To combine new and old query strings, use the [[QSA]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```